# Google voice input with suggestions to PC

Tags: android, input, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, remote-control

I need to input text to PC by voice. I have my Ubuntu PC and my Android smartphone.

I find the simplest way: remote control using KDE Connect.
I just follow to these manuals:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314824/236182
https://bash-prompt.net/guides/android-dictation/

Now it looks like:
my voice -> my Android smartphone -> Google Voice Input Keyboard -> KDE connect -> my wifi router -> my Ubuntu PC

The issue: 
Google Voice Input Keyboard can stress words and **suggest variants** of recognizing. But KDE Connect just sends (to my PC) the words ASAP so **I can't use suggestions.**

Any idea how to use suggestions?

I think suggestions would work if KDE connect has some buffer textbox. It looks like I input and correct my text in the buffer textbox on my smartphone, then click 'send' and this text sends to PC.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue using Automate application on my android smartphone. I built a small HTTP server on my Ubuntu that receives recognition results from Automate. The server uses xdotool to type text.